# ES6 destructure to "this"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Trying ES6 destructuring.

I am using this code in React class constructor:

```
let { class, ...rest } = props;
```

The above code works. But I need the variables in `this.class` and `this.rest`.

I have this code and it works:

```
let { classes, ...rest } = props; 
this.classes = classes; 
this.rest = rest;
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
{ this.classes, ...this.rest } = props;
```

Comment: Are you using a functional or class component? Also not really clear what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I am using react class component

Comment: I can't think of a particularly elegant one-liner way to do it, but you could `Object.assign(this, { classes, rest })` or `Object.assign(this, { rest: { ...props }, classes: props.classes })`

Comment: The way you are doing it and the way @rayhatfield has suggested are correct. However I feel there might not be a need to copy props to class variables as you could just access them from props whereever needed

Comment: Please remember that readable, easy to understand code is more important than saving a few characters of typing.  Go for clarity first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use renaming properties, though unfortunately it involves a bit of repetition:

```
({ classes: this.classes, ...this.rest } = props);
```

`classes` is the name of the property we're getting off of `props`; `this.classes` is the name of the variable it is getting assigned to. With `this.rest`, we obviously don't need to name the original property name.

Demo:

```js
function Foo(props) {
    ({ classes: this.classes, ...this.rest } = props);
}

const props = {
  classes: 'some clases',
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B'
}

console.log(new Foo(props));
```

Comment: Damm this is even cleaner +1

Comment: Neat, but I'm conflicted whether code that requires a fairly advanced level of understanding to follow what it's doing is actually better code.

Comment: @jfriend00: I could see your point against e.g. `!!~...indexOf` idiom; but this is not exactly code golf, it's merely using modern ES destructuring syntax. I would not call it "advanced", no more than using `Set` or `class`.

Answer (score 0):

One trickier way to achieve is using a function binded with desired `this`

Here renaming is the key, what happens here is it picks the value from `props` and assign it to whatever we rename to

```
({ classes:this.classes,...this.rest } = props)
```

So this is actually same as

```
this.classes = props.classes;
this.rest = all the properties expect those which are already destrucutred
```

You can paste your code here and see simplified version [`Babel`](https://babeljs.io/repl)

---

```js
const props = {
  classes: 'some clases',
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B'
}

let tempThis = {}
console.log(tempThis)

let getMeValuesOnThis = function(props) {
  ({ classes:this.classes,...this.rest } = props)
}.bind(tempThis)

getMeValuesOnThis(props)

console.log('---values after function execution---')
console.log(tempThis)
```

[`ray`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003656/es6-destructure-to-this/58003932#comment102412367_58003656) already suggested a way to do this using `Object.assign` in comments

Comment: Your suggestion with `bind` does not make any sense. If `this` in your example is the window object the the output be _"correct"_, but not due to the `bind`, you could remove `bind` and have the same output.

Comment: @t.niese well you're right, but the same can be done, in any scope where your `this` may be different from `window` object, isn't it ?

Comment: I downvoted and I already said that `bind` does not make any sense here. `.bind(this)` does not have any effect on the lookup of the variables `classes` and `rest`. Writing `bind({})` would lead to the exact same result in your example. `bind` has only an effect on the `this` within that function, but not on the lookup of the other variables and there is no `this` used within the function.

Comment: @t.niese oh got it, thanks for pointing out i appreciate your comments, updated :)